# OnStop method on windows service not being called if there are tasks that are attempting to access unavailable WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, threadpool

Today I ran into a bit of a problem with Windows Service.

Service itself has been working fine for over a year and it's main job is to serve TCP clients with stream of data.

Not long ago, I have added calls to WCF service to send some information about the data streams.

To prevent these WCF calls from severely influencing already existing logic, I used

```
Task.Run(() => {
    using(var proxy = new WCFProxy("configurationName"))
    {
         proxy.WCFClientMethod()
    }
});
```

This works well but I have noticed that windows service gets stuck in Stopping state if I attempt to stop it via services.msc while the remote WCF service is unavailable.

Stopping service is successful if remote WCF service is available or when it becomes available during windows service being stuck in Stopping state.

After a bit of debugging I found out that `OnStop` method is not being called.

I have found several articles on the internet about OnStop method not being called until all tasks in `ThreadPool` are finished. But I am not sure if this has anything to do with this problem, mainly because AFAIK tasks in `ThreadPool` should finish anyway, no matter if they `faulted(EndpointNotFoundException)` or not.

I would be grateful for any ideas on how to fix this issue(using Thread instead of Task.Run is not a good option as there are many calls to WCF service and creating so many threads could cause performance issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved my problem.

Found out that WCF calls were blocking actual tasks in `ThreadPool`
which caused the call to `OnStop`method to be stuck in queue.

I've made the WCF calls asynchronous with `async/await` and everything runs smootly now.